# fetching data from website and posting on excel macro

Tags: python, data-analysis, json, macros

Is it possible that we can use python or other language to fetch json data from website and posting on ms excel for enterprise purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is.

You actually have multiple methods to choose from but one of the easiest is to use the following libraries, (all pip installable):

- To get the data from the web site: [requests](http://python-requests.org), *(pip install requests to install).*
- To read the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html): json, *(built-in but there are some possible alternatives).*
- To output to an Excel compatible format - use any of:

  - [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) *(built in and can create files that Excel can read),
  - [xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org/) *(pip install - can produce XLS files)*,
  - [pyexcel](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel) *(pip install - can produce multiple formats of file)*,
  - [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) *(pip install - can produce XLSX files)*,
  - [win32com + Excel](https://gist.github.com/mikepsn/27dd0d768ccede849051) - *(pip install - can produce XLSX files)* ***the only option that requires Excel on the machine getting the data.***